# TI Photodiode Trans impedance amplifier Circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, analog, spice, operational-amplifier

I am designing a Photodiode(Vishay/ current of 15uA) circuit amplifier (TI ) in SIMetrix.
frequency of Photodiode is 1MHz. I choose an Amplifier from TI as OPA355_Q1(spice model imported from TI) and I used exactly their application circuit with the model of photodiode as you can see on the pic below;
[image]

the response I get is as following:

[image]

I should have gotten an amplification and no negative value as well. but I can`t see why. I have tried with another OP (OPA380) even with less GBP and it show better result. I doubt the model spice of OPA355 failed but not certain. how can I check that my spice model is working and tthen do you think my circuit is correct?

Comment: Does that OpAmp guarantee performance, with only  5 volts?

Comment: yes and in the datasheet it is written it can work even with 2.5V